# Creating multiple subnets in order per availability zone with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, subnet, cidr, availability-zone

New to Terraform and trying to create the following VPC from Adrian Cantril's class using the DRY method.

[VPC Diagram](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/acantril/aws-sa-associate-saac03/main/0800-VIRTUAL_PRIVATE_CLOUD(VPC)/00_LEARNINGAIDS/VPCStucture-1.png)

I can get the first 4 subnets created but when I try to repeat it, it duplicates it per AZ giving me an error.

I have tried a few other things that created 1 subnet per AZ, e.g. 10.16.0.0/20 in AZ A, 10.16.16.0 /20 in AZ B, etc..

Below is a snippet of the code I am using.

```
variable "vpc_cidr" {
  type    = string
  default = "10.16.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets-az-a" {
  count             = 4
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 4, count.index)
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[0]
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets-az-b" {
  count             = 4
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 4, count.index)
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[1]
```

Comment: Ok, but you forgot to explain what's wrong with the code. Any errors?

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack Overflow. It returns an error that there are duplicate subnets upon apply. It tries to create the same 4 subnets in each AZ. 10.16.0.0, 10.16.16.0, etc..



`Error: creating EC2 Subnet: InvalidSubnet.Conflict: The CIDR '10.16.32.0/20' conflicts with another subnet`



I was able to get it to work if I manually enter in each subnet but I figured that is not best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be pretty DRY:

```
locals {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  subnets = {
    for i, v in setproduct(["a", "b", "c"], ["reserved", "db", "app", "web"]) :
    "${local.region}${v[0]}-${v[1]}" =>
    {
      az   = "${local.region}${v[0]}"
      cidr = cidrsubnet("10.16.0.0/16", 4, i)
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "this" {
  for_each          = local.subnets

  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block        = each.value.cidr
  availability_zone = each.value.az
}
```

This will create 12 subnets as per the [diagram](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/acantril/aws-sa-associate-saac03/main/0800-VIRTUAL_PRIVATE_CLOUD(VPC)/00_LEARNINGAIDS/VPCStucture-1.png).

`locals.subnets` looks like this:

```
subnets = {
  "us-east-1a-reserved" = {
    "az" = "us-east-1a"
    "cidr" = "10.16.0.0/20"
  }
  "us-east-1a-db" = {
    "az" = "us-east-1a"
    "cidr" = "10.16.16.0/20"
  }
  "us-east-1a-app" = {
    "az" = "us-east-1a"
    "cidr" = "10.16.32.0/20"
  }
  "us-east-1a-web" = {
    "az" = "us-east-1a"
    "cidr" = "10.16.48.0/20"
  }
  "us-east-1b-reserved" = {
    "az" = "us-east-1b"
    "cidr" = "10.16.64.0/20"
  }
  // ... and so on
}
```

This `for_each` approach is more usable than the `count` variants because you can access the created subnets as follows: `aws_subnet.this["us-east-1a-reserved"].arn` as opposed to `aws_subnet.this[3].arn`.

See [setproduct](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setproduct) and [for expressions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#result-types) to understand what's going on in `locals.subnets`.

On a related note, it's a good idea to try to create a VPC and subnets from scratch when you are learning, but if you go to production, I'd recommend using this Terraform VPC module - https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a shot once I understand it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simpler way to achieve this:

```
# Loop up Availability Zones.
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

# Create subnets.
resource "aws_subnet" "default" {
  count             = 3
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.default.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.${count.index}.0/24"
  availability_zone  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
}
```